# Python -- Adding digits in a large number fails

Tags: python

I'm working on a bit of code that adds up all the digits of a number and prints out the sum:

```
number = #some big 50+ bit number
sum = 0

while number != 0:
    sum += number % 10
    number = int(number/10)

print(sum)
```

I thought this was a pretty slick solution but when I added print statements to check, it wasn't dividing correctly when the number was very large. I thought that because I was using python 3.8 that I could have arbitrarily large numbers. Is this not the case or am I asking the wrong question?

I tried replacing `number = int(number/10)` to both `number = math.trunc(number/10)` and `number = math.floor(number/10)` and got the same results for both of those as well

Comment: Every version of python (as far as I know) has arbitrarily large ints.

Comment: You want to go for integer division (`numer//10`), the reason is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Arbitrarily large *integers* @Xilpex

Comment: @MarkMeyer -- Yes, I meant that.

Comment: Do not call your variable `sum` - it is a built-in function.

Answer (score 6):

The `/` operator does float division. You need `//` for integer division. So, use:

```
number = #some big 50+ bit number
s = 0

while number != 0:
    s += number % 10
    number = int(number//10)

print(s)
```

Dividing as floats may not work since you lose precision.

Comment: Still, do not call your variable `sum`. And there is no need for `int()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this way. Convert number into string and loop through string

```
number = # big number
S = 0
for x in str(number):
  S += int(x)
print(S)
```